# Why does logging into chat open a new tab?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, login

When I navigate directly to a chat room (e.g. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) before hitting any other SE site I am not logged in yet so on the bottom where you normally would type your message is replaced with a message asking you to log in.

I click the link to log in and a new tab opens which then automatically logs in and then procedes to open up the chat room I had tried to access prior to logging in. I now have two tabs open - one where I am logged in and one where I am not. I now have to close the tab that I originally used to get to the site.

It would seem to me that if the login page will redirect back to the previous page being visited prior to logging in that opening in a new tab does not add any value.

Is there a reason behind this? It's not really a big deal and I could either close the second tab or just log in prior to going to a chat site but curiosity has me asking the question.

Thanks!

(Not sure if its a bug or feature which would determine bug or support tag so I marked it as discussion. If anyone of higher power wants to properly tag it and remove this message that would be great!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great point. All links within the room by default open in a new tab, since navigating essentially means you're leaving the room. The only exception are the links in the sidebar to the other rooms you're in, since going to a different room still considers you to be in this room.

But the login link is another good candidate for an exception here; in particular since (as you said) you'll be redirected back to the room anyway.